# serious errors were found while checking the disk for /

Tags: 14.04

Ubuntu 14.04 after installation:

serious errors while checking for drive /.

[image]

Comment: well no question has been answered, its better to post answer here

Comment: @Leonard I do not see question and an answer here ;) And what to do is stated in the image.